# amplxe-sepreg.exe missing from VTune

Tags: windows, intel, intel-vtune

When I try to use hardware event-based profiling in VTune (Profiler 2020), I get the error message

```
Cannot enable Hardware Event-based Sampling due to a problem with the driver (sep*/sepdrv*). Check that the driver is running and the driver group is in the current user group list. See the "Sampling Drivers" help topic for further details.
```

In the [Sampling Drivers](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-help-sep-driver) section of the use guide it says

> [Windows* targets](https://software.intel.com/en-us/vtune-help-installing-the-sampling-drivers-for-windows-targets): Verify the sampling driver is installed correctly. If required, install the driver.

then asks me to run `amplxe-sepreg.exe`. This is missing from the `bin32` directory. I have reinstalled multiple times.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After uninstalling again and installing from the `oneAPI` package, it worked.

Comment: Seems like you should have marked the other answer as correct.  All you did was follow his advise.

Comment: I did this before he answered. After installing oneAPI, it just worked, I didn’t even need to look for amplxe-sepreg. It was the system studio version that didn’t have amplxe-sepreg.

Answer (score 1):

The amplxe-sepreg.exe application could be found  in bin64 folderfor oneAPI beta07 toolkit,

Comment: I have already gotten it to work with oneAPI, it was System Studio that I was using before which didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error motivating this question could be resolved by running vtune as administrator.